# Prolog Recursion on List

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I am trying to understand how this prolog program works, and, as a beginner, I'm having some difficulty.  The program is as follows:

```
initialCan([w, b, w, w, w]).
scholten([X], X).
scholten([X, X | Z], Answer) :- scholten([b | Z], Answer).
scholten([X, Y | Z], Answer) :- scholten([w | Z], Answer).
run(Answer) :- initialCan(L), scholten(L, Answer).
```

Here is the trace from running it through the first solution.

```
{trace}
| ?- run(A).
      1    1  Call: run(_17) ? 
      2    2  Call: initialCan(_84) ? 
      2    2  Exit: initialCan([w,b,w,w,w]) ? 
      3    2  Call: scholten([w,b,w,w,w],_17) ? 
      4    3  Call: scholten([w,w,w,w],_17) ? 
      5    4  Call: scholten([b,w,w],_17) ? 
      6    5  Call: scholten([w,w],_17) ? 
      7    6  Call: scholten([b],_17) ? 
      7    6  Exit: scholten([b],b) ? 
      6    5  Exit: scholten([w,w],b) ? 
      5    4  Exit: scholten([b,w,w],b) ? 
      4    3  Exit: scholten([w,w,w,w],b) ? 
      3    2  Exit: scholten([w,b,w,w,w],b) ? 
      1    1  Exit: run(b) ? 

A = b ?
```

The thing I'm having trouble understanding is how the recursive calls work.  What exactly happens with

```
scholten([X, X | Z], Answer) :- scholten([b | Z], Answer).
```

What is most confusing is the difference between [X, X | Z] and [b | Z].  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule in question says that if `scholten` sees a list that starts with two identical elements, these two elements need to be replaced with a single `b`. The list `[b | Z]` is shorter by one element than the `[X, X | Z]`.

Note that the rule below

```
scholten([X, Y | Z], Answer) :- scholten([w | Z], Answer).
```

has a singleton (i.e. unused anywhere else) variable `Y`. You should change the rule to

```
scholten([X, Y | Z], Answer) :- X \= Y, scholten([w | Z], Answer).
```

to ensure that `X` does not equal `Y`, preventing this rule from matching the same arguments as the `[X, X | Z]` one.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I couldn't wrap my head around the fact that it is checking if the first two elements are the same or different.